# Should I buy a lawn mower with or without a cord?

Tags: lawn-mower

The land I have to mow on is rough and rather large. I must decide if I should buy a corded lawnmower or not and I am looking for help making the right purchasing decision. I was hoping someone with first hand experience would care to weigh in on the matter? In truth, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I once owned a 3/4 acre lawn as part of a 2 1/2 acre parcel in the country. We mowed our huge front lawn (which was on the side of a fairly steep hill) for a couple of years with a gasoline-powered mower and then we asked ourselves "Why are we doing this?". It took over an hour to mow, neither my wife nor I liked doing it, and there was literally no one around to enjoy it but us. And we basically never walked it. So we stopped & mowed two much, much smaller lawns and a path around the formerly mown lawn for maintenance & to keep the ticks at bay. So - is there a reason you're mowing this lawn?

Comment: The significance of the cord itself tends to be overlooked.  If you need 200 ft the cord will  probably be heavier than the mower and substantial cost .  The longer ,the heavier the gage . You will probably need 14 gage; price that ! I use 100 ft of 16 gage , enough for a blower or a weedeater ; not a mower . It is a serious pain in the as* to handle  just for blowing or weedeating much less mowing. Recently had to remove a small tree with a baby electric chain saw ; had to compromise with 50 ft of 14ga + 50 ft of 16 ga.  It is an amperage X resistance problem.

Answer (score 1):

The first criterion is a mower that is big and powerful enough to do the job efficiently. Corded mowers tend to be small and not very powerful (the maximum power is limited by what is available from a standard household power socket, and/or the maximum safe current on the cable). On the other hand, a mower with a battery too small to finish the job in one go is also annoying and time wasting, or more expensive if you fix the problem by getting an extra battery pack.

If those criteria still leave you a choice between corded and cordless, handling the cord while mowing is an extra task you have to do, and is more extra effort if you need a longer cord for a bigger lawn.

Comment: But small and light could be an advantage, if you have storage issue.

Answer (score 1):

We don't know the size of you lawn, so it is difficult to give you a precise answer, but we can help you to decide.

I have all kind of mowers.

- electric mowers (so corded): very handy for small surface: small, light and quick to do regular cuts. I find it need less maintenance. Possibly it requires to have a second person to help with cable (especially if you have complex geometries and nice flowers). On the other hand, they are small, so it is easier to move it between flowers.
- cordless mower: usually much more powerful, so you can use also less regularly and for large surfaces. They requires some more maintenance. You may have them with traction (moving wheels), which help on large surfaces (and on not flat gardens). Some new models (like Grin) mulch grass, so you doesn't have to collect (which is annoying on large gardens [collection and compost]). If you want to be more "green", you may use Aspen gas (for 4 stroke engines).
- On larger gardens, a lawn law-mower, you may get a ride-on-version: more maintenance, it needs more space to turn. Depending on models you may have cutter behind wheel, or under the mower. The first are larger (for storage), but you can cut better the borders, and the higher grass (on the second type, your wheel will step on.
- I have also a  sickle-bar mower, for larger surfaces, which I cut less. I use the hay. Only for larger surfaces, but you can keep nice flowering field, which is nice for nature (wild flowers and insects).
- and string cutter. This is mostly for borders and places with many rocks. Result is not so good (and regular) as the other, but for some places you may need it.

There are also non-motored lawn mowers (which I would not recommend, but if you want to make a lot of exercise), and Scythe/Sickle (now is again fashionable, but I would use them only to replace the sickle-bar mower. Probably not.).

So you see, there are many option. It is difficult to find the best one. I would go to corded lawn mower if you have a small lawn. Non corded lawn mower on the other cases. You will know it when you will need an additional machine.

Answer (score 0):

I would always choose a cordless lawnmower regardless of the size of the property. Corded lawn mowers, in my experience, are more of a hassle than they are worth. That being said, if your property is large and rough than you have all the more reason to go cordless.

Comment: Some people will argue the opposite: starting a cordless mower first time on spring could be difficult.

Answer (score 0):

There are also petrol (gas) mowers. In the UK they are commonly used for larger lawns. You may also want to look at the direction of cutting, depending on whether you want stripes in your lawn or not.